# drupal_get_destination() gets garbled url

Tags: drupal, url

```
$url =  drupal_get_destination();

print $url;
```

The output is garbled:~

*destination=node%2Fgoto%2Fhttp%3A%2Fwww.graphicdesignblog.org%2Fstreet-graffiti-illusions*

How can I get a clean url string? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this url is not garbled, its encoded to be added as a parameter to a goto url. You can read [this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_get_destination/6) page.

If you want to see the url it redirects to, you can use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php), but remember not to add a decoded url to the query string.